# Adsense Ads not displaying in android

Tags: android

I am implementing Adsense in my application. I have the publisher id and I have implemented 
the code in my application using Google Adsense SDK tutorial. But Ads are not displaying in my 
application.

Here is my code :

AdSenseSpec adSenseSpec = new AdSenseSpec("pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
            .setCompanyName("company name while registering in google Adsense") 
            .setAppName("Application name")
            .setAdTestEnabled(false);

```
  GoogleAdView adView = (GoogleAdView) findViewById(R.id.adview);
       adView.setEnabled(true);
       adView.showAds(adSenseSpec);
```

These is getting in logcat :

05-18 13:19:41.077: WARN/webcore(8506): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
05-18 13:19:43.377: VERBOSE/NotificationService(171): [cancelNotificationWithTag]::::: pkg:android id:-669611123
05-18 13:19:43.859: WARN/PowerManagerService(171): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
05-18 13:19:44.297: WARN/webcore(8506): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

Can any body have any clue?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: from where did you get googleadview.jar? isnt adsense integrated with admob?

Comment: AFAIK you are not permitted to use AdSense in an application. AdMob will use AdSense to backfill any unfilled ad requests, and you should look to use AdMob's SDK

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing it like this(this is for the newer version)

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView); 
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```